# BigQuery stream to front-end with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stream, google-bigquery

I'm trying to read a query from [BigQuery](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/BigQuery.html) and stream it to the front-end. In Node.js-land with Express, this would be:

```js
app.get('/endpoint', (req, res) => {
  bigQuery.createQueryStream(query).pipe(res);
});
```

However, `createQueryStream()` does **not** create a Node.js stream, instead it's a custom stream object that returns *table rows* and as such it fails:

> (node:21236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type object

This is confirmed in the [official documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/BigQuery.html#createQueryStream):

```js
bigquery.createQueryStream(query)
  .on('data', function(row) {
    // row is a result from your query.
  })
```

So, is there a way to stream BigQuery data to the front-end? I've thought two potential solutions but wanted to know if anyone knows a better way:

- `JSON.stringify()` the row and return `JSONL` instead of plain `JSON`. This adds a front-end burden to decode it, but makes it fairly easy on both sides.
- Move to the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/) and do actual streaming with [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) like: `request(url, { body: { query, params } }).pipe(res)` (or whatever is the specific API, haven't dug there yet).

I was confused that a Node.js library that says that it does streaming doesn't work with Node.js native streams, but this seems to be the case.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Kindof! We ended up building a JSON manually and then "streaming" each row in a very hacky way. But we were trying to stream large amounts of data, and BigQuery was being slow anyway. We moved to Python at some point (for other reasons!) and were hoping that the library there would be more mature, but no, it was actually _a lot worse_.

Comment: @tjbandes this is what we ended up doing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64746763/12271991

Comment: I see, thanks for the update! It seems like concatenating the results with `[` `,` `]` kind of defeats the purpose of streaming though, right? I suppose you're saving memory on the server side, but the client still has to wait for the whole array before it can `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Yes, totally agreed. I'm not even sure we are saving memory on the server side but we might. Another small advantage is that the data is sent in chunks so it'll be faster this way vs waiting and sending it all at once _after the last chunk_ arrives on the server (lower backend<->frontend bandwidth needs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up making an implementation that stitched together the reply from BigQuery into a big JSON array:

```js
exports.stream = (query, params, res) => {
  // Light testing for descriptive errors in the parameters
  for (let key in params) {
    if (typeof params[key] === "number" && isNaN(params[key])) {
      throw new TypeError(`The parameter "${key}" should be a number`);
    }
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let prev = false;

    const onData = row => {
      try {
        // Only handle it when there's a row
        if (!row) return;

        // There was a previous row written before, so add a comma
        if (prev) {
          res.write(",");
        }
        res.write(stringify(row));
        prev = true;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Cannot parse row:", error);
        // Just ignore it, don't write this frame
      }
    };

    const onEnd = () => {
      res.write("]");
      res.end();
      resolve();
    };

    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
    res.write("[");
    bigQuery
      .createQueryStream({ query, params })
      .on("error", reject)
      .on("data", onData)
      .on("end", onEnd);
  });
};
```

It will build a large JSON array by stitching together:

```
[   // <- First character sent
stringify(row1)   // <- First row
,   // <- add comma on second row iteration
stringify(row2)   // <- Second row
...
stringify(rowN)   // <- Last row
]   // <- Send the "]" character to close the array
```

This has the advantages:

- The data is sent as soon as available, so the bandwidth needs are lower.
- (depends on BigQuery implementation) lower memory needs on the server side since not all the data is hold at once in memory, only small chunks.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery is intended to be used with a wide array of different client libraries written for different programming languages, and therefore, it does not return nodejs-specific data structures, but rather, more general structures which are common to mostly any structured programming language, such as objects. Answering to your questions, yes, there is a way to stream BigQuery data to the front-end, but this is a rather personal choice, because all it entails is converting from one data type to another. However, I would say the most straight-forward way to do this is by calling `JSON.stringify()`, which you have already mentioned.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Sure, but this is a Node.js library that says it does streaming so I think it's very safe to think [it does Node.js streaming](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html). The naming is quite confusing here then, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Francisco It does Node.js streaming, you are right, but the stream it returns is a standard data type in Node.js. The doc you shared says that the returned object is a readable stream object, so you can convert it to string in a number of ways. One of them being this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-to-string)

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant that I thought it would do Node.js streaming but _it does not_, you cannot `.pipe()` straight to a Node.js ReadableStream since it'll throw an error. So it's not a Node.js stream compatible library. That's why I was confused, it seems BigQuery does not support Node.js Streams, it just supports something that looks similar but works differently.